# How to make a share button

Tags: java, android

I would like to add a share button that opens something like this.

[image: Share]

I am using this source from [the official Android site](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#share-interaction-data)

I want to send standard text so I thought I should use this part:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null);
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

But I have no idea where to place the code.
How would I do it if I wanted to place it in 1 of these 3 spots?

[image: Share locations]

I would prefer to have it in the Menu or up top and just remove the button below but I am open to any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a click event listener to the `FloatingActionButton`:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        share();
    }
});

private void share(){
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    
    Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null);
    startActivity(shareIntent);
}
```

To handle a menu item click:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.yourItemId:
        share();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me.
Is there anyway to do this on top of the screen next to the settings button?

Comment: @RobinGroot Look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66140246/13146129)

Answer (score 0):

From your comment : `This worked for me. Is there anyway to do this on top of the screen next to the settings button?`

You have to create `menu` directory in `resource/res`. Then, create a menu. Add following source code to menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item  android:id="@+id/share"
        android:title="Shar"/>
</menu>
```

Add following source code to `MainActivity`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.share:
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

            Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null);
            startActivity(shareIntent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger this code from your navigation drawer, then you need to override the onNavigationItemSelected method in your calling activity like this

```
 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

       case R.id.nav_share: {
      Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

            Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null);
            startActivity(shareIntent);
            break;
        }  
    }
    //close navigation drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Identify the ID of the menu item, then place the code accordingly.